# Update bat file output from Qthread to Gui

Tags: python, batch-file, pyqt4, popen, qthread

I am a system administrator and this is the first time I am trying to achieve something using Python. I am working on a small python tool that will run a bat file in a Qthread. On the GUI I have a textedit box where I want to update output/error from the bat file.

Here is the code I have so far,

QThread -

```
class runbat(QtCore.QThread):
    line_printed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(runbat, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        popen = subprocess.Popen("install.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        lines_iterator = iter(popen.stdout.readline, b"")
        for line in lines_iterator:
        self.line_printed.emit(line)
```

From main -

```
self.batfile.line_printed.connect(self.batout)

def batout(self, line):
    cursor = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(line)
    self.ui.textEdit.ensureCursorVisible()
```

but I am getting - TypeError: runbat.line_printed[str].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bytes'. Another question is does stdout catches errors or just output, What do I need to catch the errors as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I was able to get it to work by changing the code to following.

in Qthread

```
line_printed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bytes)
```

in main

```
def batout(self, line):
    output = str(line, encoding='utf-8')
    cursor = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(output)
    self.ui.textEdit.ensureCursorVisible()
```

Basically the out put was in bytes and I had to convert it to string. Its working as expected with this changes however if anyone have a better solution I would love to try it. Thank you all.